# extract data from service with angular

Tags: arrays, json, angular, extract, subscribe

I am trying to extract **firstname** fields from a json response service with angular and return an array full of firstnames.

this the the json object :

```
{
    "hits": {
        "hits": [
            {
                "_id": "BKZujHgB0urOc7uDCrf5",
                "_index": "names",
                "_score": 1.0,
                "_source": {
                    "firstname": "Alicia"
                },
                "_type": "_doc"
            },
            {
                "_id": "BaZujHgB0urOc7uDL7e2",
                "_index": "names",
                "_score": 1.0,
                "_source": {
                    "firstname": "Alice"
                },
                "_type": "_doc"
            }
        ]
        
}
```

i have created a service to consume the webservice that returns the json object without using observables. appService.ts

```
public autoComplete(name: string) {

    const params = new HttpParams()
        .set('name', name);
    return this.httpClient.get(this.host, { params});
```

and in the app.component.ts I Have created a function that calls the service  and implemented it in ngOnInit() ,i have followed the autocomplete angular material with a little modification . but i am always having errors of **Cannot read property 'hits' of undefined**

```
ngOnInit() {
   this.seachText.valueChanges.pipe(
      startWith(''),
      // delay emits
      debounceTime(300),
      // use switch map so as to cancel previous subscribed events, before creating new once
      map(value => this.lookup(value))
      ).subscribe(value => this.results$ = value);
   this.names = this.results$.hits.hits.map(h => h._source.firstname);

   console.log('resultat :', this.names);

  }
```

i dont know how to correct the error but i guess that i am wrong with the way that i am using to extract the data from  the json object comming from the service

Comment: You need to do it _inside_ the callback. Read the canonical https://stackoverflow.com/q/14220321/3001761

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your stream is asychronous, so when *names* is assigned, is certainly never has emitted yet.

To fix that, you can use a second map operator for example.
This way you change the output to your liking and the end value is what you expected.

```js
this.searchText.valueChanges
      .pipe(
        startWith(""),
        debounceTime(300),
        map(value => this.appService.autoComplete(value)),
        map(results => results.hits.hits.map(hit => hit._source.firstname))
      )
      .subscribe(value => (this.results = value));
```

Check out this repoduction on StackBlitz : https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackoverflow-67142850

If ever you want your *autoComplete* method to return an observable, just replace **map** with **switchMap** when consuming it.

Comment: thanks for ur response , but still the same problem **Cannot read property 'hits' of undefined** this autocomplete method    `public autoComplete(name: string) {

    const params = new HttpParams()
        .set('name', name);
    return this.httpClient.get(this.host, { params});
}`                                                                                                                                                  i dont know where the problem exist

Comment: I'm afraid that without providing more context we won't be able to help more on that.

Comment: ok @Simon , this is my app.component.html  ` <input type="text" matInput   [matAutocomplete]="auto"
                [formControl]="searchText">
                <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" >
                  <mat-option *ngFor="let option of results | async" [value]="option">
                    {{option}}
                  </mat-option>
                </mat-autocomplete>`    tslint make an underline under hits and tell me that **"Property 'hits' does not exist on type 'Observable <Object>'"**

Comment: For the lint, you should either strongly type your object or use any.
As for the runtime error, firstly you should remove the async pipe since results is not an Observable.

Answer (score 0):

First, let me use a code snippet to simplfied the error.

```
let a;

of(2).subscribe((res) => {
   a = res;
   console.log("res");  // Async code, executed after sync code
})

console.log(a); // syn code. This log is excuted first
```

The output will be

```
// undefiend 
// 2;
```

In your case, you use `results.hits` before it receives a value. What it actually do is read hits of undefiend. This is where the error occurs.

To fix the error, you need to consider **move** `this.names = this.results$.hits.hits.map(h => h._source.firstname);` to inside of your subscription to obverable or use **obersable operators** to set the value asynchrounsly.

Comment: i tried to move `this.names = this.results$.hits.hits.map(h => h._source.firstname);`to inside of my subscription but still the same error **Cannot read property 'hits' of undefined**this is my full ngOnInit()  `ngOnInit() {this.searchText.valueChanges.pipe( startWith(''),debounceTime(300),map(value => this.appService.autoComplete(value)),).subscribe((value) => {this.results = value;       this.names = this.results.hits.hits.map(h => h._source.firstname);});}
`